# Persist Laravel Nova resource filters across sessions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a Laravel Nova 4 application, and I need to implement a functionality where the filters applied to the resources can be persisted across sessions. In other words, when a user applies a filter to a resource and then navigates away from the module, I want the filter to be saved so that when the user returns to the module, the information is displayed with the previously applied filter.

I have explored using a middleware for this purpose, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach. Currently, I'm considering storing the filter information in the user's browser local storage or session storage.

Can someone guide me on the best approach to achieve this in Laravel Nova 4? How can I store and retrieve the filter data using local storage or session storage? Any code examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, I would not do this, Laravel nova is not prepared for this, and you would need to know about the core of it, it is not documented and intended to do so